# Why is my modal not showing? Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, web-deployment

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'homepage/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'homepage/css/element.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            height:100%;
            font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
            padding-top: 100px;
        }
        header {
            font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="{% url 'index' %}"><img class="logo img" src="{% static 'homepage/img/leaves.png' %}">NAME</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'product_page' %}">ProductName`</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="navbar-btn">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#newsletterModal" class="btn btn-default">Newsletter</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'store' %}">Store</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="modal fade" id="newsletterModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newsletterModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times;</button>
                    <h4>Sign Up For Our Newsletter!</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</header>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to launch a modal when the newsletter button is clicked in the navbar but the modal is not showing. I followed some other stack overflow posts and tried to put the modal div outside the navbar among other tricks but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Any other suggestions with my code would also be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide this as a runnable snippet and remove/replace the `{% ... %}` items? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: What is the aria-hidden=true attribute of your modal?  Could it be keeping it hidden?

Comment: @JeffMatthews The `aria-hidden` attribute is just for screen readers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tested your modal and it's working fine. The only possible reason is that you either aren't loading one of the following files OR you are loading an outdated version of some of them.

So, make you sure you are loading all of the following files (in that order):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And also make sure that you are loading (in the head section) an up-to-date version of the css which is this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: This worked for me - I only needed the bootstrap js and jquery tags. thanks!